# How to resolve invalid syntax issue?

Tags: python

I have this issue and can't seem to find a resolution to it. It keeps showing me on line 15 invalid syntax. What's wrong with it?

```
print("Shirt Order")
print()

colour = input("What colour of the shirt? Blue or White: ")
if colour.lower() == "blue":
    size = input("What size of the shirt? (S/M/L): ")
    if size.lower() == "l":
        print("Sorry, we do not have that size available.")
elif size.lower() == "m":
    print("You have selected a blue shirt in size medium, that will be $9 please.")
elif size.lower() == "s":
    print("You have selected a blue shirt in size small, that will be $5.50 please.")
else:
    print("Sorry, your order was not recognized, please try again.")
elif colour.lower() == "white":
    size = input("What size of the shirt? (S/M/L): ")
    if size.lower() == "l":
        print("You have selected a white shirt in size large, that will be $10 please.")
elif size.lower() == "m":
    print("You have selected a white shirt in size medium, that will be $9 please.")
elif size.lower() == "s":
    print("Sorry, we do not have that size available.")
else:
    print("Sorry, your order was not recognized, please try again.")
```

Comment: Double-check your indentation; it matters in Python. Also it's probably worth considering other ways of structuring this code to separate the logic from the data, thinking about how much of a pain it would currently be to add red and/or XL shirts.

Comment: You can't have `elif` after `else`, that would never be reached.

Comment: It looks like the first two elifs and the following else should all be indented to the same level as `if size.lower() == 'l'`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indent code strongly.

**this is what your code should look like**

```
print("Shirt Order")
print()

colour = input("What colour of the shirt? Blue or White: ")
if colour.lower() == "blue":
    size = input("What size of the shirt? (S/M/L): ")
    if size.lower() == "l":
        print("Sorry, we do not have that size available.")
    elif size.lower() == "m":
        print("You have selected a blue shirt in size medium, that will be $9 please.")
    elif size.lower() == "s":
        print("You have selected a blue shirt in size small, that will be $5.50 please.")
    else:
        print("Sorry, your order was not recognized, please try again.")
elif colour.lower() == "white":
    size = input("What size of the shirt? (S/M/L): ")
    if size.lower() == "l":
        print("You have selected a white shirt in size large, that will be $10 please.")
    elif size.lower() == "m":
        print("You have selected a white shirt in size medium, that will be $9 please.")
    elif size.lower() == "s":
        print("Sorry, we do not have that size available.")
    else:
        print("Sorry, your order was not recognized, please try again.")
```

Answer (score 1):

There is two types of errors:

1] size variable is not defined in the block of indentation where other elif and else instruction lies

2] In line 15, this syntax error throws as putting elif control after else should not be done. Else always should be put at last of if-elif chain.

You should put else on last of if-elif chain so that syntax follows right